# Trying to add get_the_title hook to this line

Tags: php, css

Hi creating a contact form.

Trying to add the get_the_title() to this line of code:

```
<?php echo '<textarea style="margin-left: 15px; width: 246px;" rows="3" cols="28" placeholder="I am interested in:" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';?>
```

Here is the complete code of form:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background-color: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
    <?php echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';?>
    <?php echo '<h5>';?>
    <?php echo 'Ask a question <br/>';?>
    <?php echo '</h5>';?>
    <?php echo '<p>';?>
    <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Your Name (required)" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
    <?php echo '</p>';?>
    <?php echo '<p>';?>
    <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="email" placeholder="E-mail (required)" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
    <?php echo '</p>';?>
    <?php echo '<p>';?>
  <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Phone (required)" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
  <?php echo '</p>';?>
  <?php echo '<p>';?>
  <?php echo '<textarea style="margin-left: 15px; width: 246px;" rows="3" cols="28" placeholder="I am interested in: " name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';?>
  <?php echo '</p>';?>
  <?php echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Contact Agent" style="border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; margin-left: 15px; width: 247px; height: 38px; background-color: #27ae60;"></p>';?>
  <?php echo '</form>';?>
    <?php echo '<p style="font-size: x-small; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 22px;">';?>
    <?php echo 'By sending a request you agree to our Privacy Policy';?>
    <?php echo '</p>';?>
```

Here is picture of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

The "I am interested in:" is showing and was easily called by placeholder="I am interested in:. I would also like to call the post title of which ever post this form is displayed on behind the default placeholder "I am interested in:" as in the pic I added. The highlighted text is the post title being fetched.

Here is the link where you can see it on the web http://teamambrose.realtor/property/mls-t3110937-9313-mandrake-ct-tampa-fl-33647/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe,   have you tried

```
....placeholder="I am interested in: '.get_the_title().' "....
```

also you don't need all those php's.  The code can be cleaner, easier to read.  One can do either:

```
<?php 
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
echo '<h5>';
echo 'Ask a question <br/>';
?>
```

etc

or

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );>" method="post">
<h5>Ask a question </h5>
```